# PHP: Match strange dash with preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have big problems to match this character: –

It's something called a "en dash" U+2013 (according to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)

It's a match with - in my test environment (windows and php 5.2.11) but fails on the production servers (ubuntu and php 5.3.2). Even \x2013 fails there.

Any suggestions how to match this strange character? Or how to config php to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match ('~\xe2\x80\x93~', $string))
{
    echo "En Dash found";
}
```

I believe you've got an UTF-8 encoding, don't you?

Comment: You can just type it directly into the PHP file, unescaped. PHP supports UTF-8 strings, as long you can treat them as opaque. "/–/" will match (with a literal en-dash).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try use the "u" flag on the expression which makes the expression compatible with utf-8: [regex pattern modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

so your expression would be `"/[somepatter]/u"`